# Obtain the coordinates x and y using TapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geometry, core-graphics, uitapgesturerecognizer

I derive the x and y coordinates of the finger on the screen using UITapGestureRecognizer. How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void) handleTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {

    CGPoint tapPoint = [sender locationInView:someView];
    int tapX = (int) tapPoint.x;
    int tapY = (int) tapPoint.y;
    NSLog(@"TAPPED X:%d Y:%d", tapX, tapY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way to get touch point is from CCTouchMoved as shown below and declare the variable globally so you can use it to others as well.

Declare "CGPoint *touchLocation;" in your header file.

```
-(void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
//get locations of touch
touchLocation = [touch  locationInView:[touch view]];
NSLog(@"Touch Points are %f, %f", touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
```

}